# How to save chart as an image on the server

Tags: java, image, sockets

I am using applet and creating a chart by jcchart. Now when the chart is ploited, if the user wants to export this chart as GIF then this chart should be save as on the server directory. Can anybody help me how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually quite easy with HTTP using the HttpURLConnection class to POST the data to a servlet or a PHP script running on the web server. There's an example [here](http://www.xyzws.com/Javafaq/how-to-use-httpurlconnection-post-data-to-web-server/139) that shows how to use HttpURLConnection. You'll need to set a different content type header (image/png) and use a binary stream to output the data, but the basics are all there.

Comment: At the server side I am using classic asp as scripting language. so if I use the below code                           ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      ImageIO.write(myImage, "png", baos);

byte[] imgByte = baos.toByteArray();   where myImage is the object of BufferedImage.     and now pass this byte array to the asp page then I can create the image fle by ASP. or I will have to do any thing else. Please help me, I am new to this

Comment: That's all you need to do, but there's no point writing to a ByteArrayOutputStream, just write directly to the output stream returned by the HttpURLConnection.

Comment: can you please tell me some asp code so that I can upload the image by asp. The problem for me is to find the image name in request parameter. so if I send the image by this way how the asp classic will upload the file

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the chart is generated by the server and sent to the client via some request handler (instead of, say, in an applet on the client side).  If this is the case, then you can simply modify that request handler to look for an additional request parameter (say "`saveImage`") which, if found and affirmative, will trigger the handler to save it to a file on the local filesystem instead of (or in addition to) returning the contents directly.

So once you've exported your chart object as a PNG, say, you can simply write that byte stream to a local file using a [FileOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html), for example.

Comment: actually for ploating the chart data comes from the server by asp but is created by applet at client so how can I send the chart image to the server. I know hoe to create the image on the local file system but I have to send it to server directory